# How to get a dynamic id via 'getElementById' in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-programming, getelementbyid

First of all I've gone through most similar questions in StackOverflow and nothing is relevant.

I have a table that has dynamically created id for each td. (Example: a td has an id "0 0")

I need to access that particular td using the id. 
I tried the following code:

```
document.getElementById("\""+rowID + " " + 0 + "\"");
```

This throws "null". "rowID" is also dynamically defined.

When I try the following:

```
document.getElementById("0 0");
```

I get the following output correctly:

```
<td class=​"cell" id=​"0 0">​20​</td>​
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: spaces are not allowed in identifier

Comment: `document.getElementById(rowID +" "+0);` or `document.getElementById('"' +rowID + '0"');`

Comment: If you need to specify dynamic identifiers try to use a GUID. However, if you do need to keep track of columns as well as rows I would recommend to keep them separate as their intend is not the same as that of an element identifier. i.e: for column 2 in row 1 `<td class=​"cell" data-row-id="1" data-col-id="2">​20​</td>​` you can still query for the elements by `document.querySelector('[data-row-id="1"][data-col-id="2"]')` You can even only assign the `col-id` to `td` and `row-id` to `tr` elements if you want, depending on the required features.

Comment: Fran. This sounds interesting and DRY. But how would I dynamically define these class to a td which is also dynamically created? 

In my current code, I follow this: 

    cell.setAttribute("id", rowID + "_" + j);

Comment: I don't know what you use to generate the rows/cols but I assume from your sample, something like: `cell.setAttribute("data-row-id", rowID);` and `cell.setAttribute("data-col-id", j);` and if you want to separate it more, maybe `row.setAttribute("data-row-id", rowID);` and `cell.setAttribute("data-col-id", j);`

Comment: That should make everything pretty simple I think. So data-row-id is itself a td attribute? Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: @BhoopalanThaati: No, it's a [`data-*` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Answer (score 4):

This boils down to: How do I do string concatenation in JavaScript?

```
document.getElementById(rowID + " 0");
// or if we assume a `colID` variable:
document.getElementById(rowID + " " + colID);
```

**However**, note that you're breaking just about the only rule there is for the `id` attribute: It [cannot contain a space](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). Some browsers may let you get away with having that space (in fact, Chrome, Firefox, and IE11 all do), but it's explicitly not allowed.

Replace the space with (say) an underscore (`_`) or an `x` in both the `id` attribute and your code. E.g., `0x0`. (`id`s can start with digits, although people will tell you they can't because a CSS ID *selector* cannot start with an *unescaped* digit.)

Comment: or take an id with meaning, like `'row0col0'`.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Sure, or `0x0` as it's a fairly common way to express row+col.